# if %variable% ==, not working

Tags: batch-file

So I am making an RPG, Pokemon style fighting game (with movie characters) to test my skills, I obviously need more work. It is a batch (.bat) file, I am using notepad++. The "`Katniss`" part does work, while the other three don't work. The `%char%` (character) is set previously and the Katniss works so it can't be a problem there. The problem is something with the "`if`" statement I think. Here is a fragment of the code, I would have the whole thing but it's around 400 lines and I've narrowed it down to this section using `pause`s.

```
`:character2
cls       
REM --------------------------------------------------Characters aren't working here
if %char% == Katniss set hp=100
    set mattack1=Knife
    set rattack1=Arrow
    set rattack2=Fire Arrow
    set rattack3=Explosive Arrow
    set block1=Bow Block
    set armr=2
    set energy=140
    set m1enc=50
    set m1hpd=25
    set m2enc=25
    set r1hpd=20
    set r1enc=65
    set r2hpd=50
    set r2enc=110
    set r3hpd=75
    set r3enc=140
    set bk1md=5
    set bk1ec=50
    set defense=2
    goto corc
if %char% == Gandalf set hp=120
    set mattack1=Staff
    set mattack2=Sword
    set mgttack1=Fireball
    set mgttack2=Blast
    set mgttac2=Staff
    set block2=Magic Shield
    set block3=Sword
    set armr=0
    set energy=100
    set m1hpd=15
    set m1enc=40
    set m2hpd=40
    set m2enc=90
    set mg1hd=45
    set mg1ec=100
    set mg2hd=10
    set mg2ec=25
    set mg3hd=5
    set mg3ec=25
    set bk1md=5
    set bk1ec=80
    set bk2md=25
    set bk2ec=100
    set bk3md=3
    set bk1ec=45
    set defense=0
    goto corc`
```

I tried Yahoo Answers but the person didn't read the full question and said I needed to set `%char%`.

----***Answer***
Turned out it was the `(`

```
)
```

thing, I missed a few and that prevented the variable from being set but the `""` had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
if %char% == Katniss (
   set hp=100
   set x=1
   set y=2
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use parentheses and double quotes:

```
if "%char%"=="Katniss" (
   set "hp=100"
   set "x=1"
   set "y=2"
   ...
   goto corc
)
```